# How to manage huge trees on a standard PC?

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, gcc, tree

1. Given a root node, which should start producing a tree with about 10<sup>10</sup> (ab. 2<sup>34</sup>) nodes, is it appropriate  to use a memory-mapped file which once will contain the whole tree?
2. What operating-system-related problems may occur (file I/O, huge file support)?
3. Have C, gcc and glibc some implicit limits (pointers)?
4. Has Linux any issues/limits with large files?

Comment: 10T * node_size .. huge is an understatement :D You definitely need 64 bit OS and filesystem with large file support. Note: Are you sure you want to store this on one computer node? :/ A cluster seems to be better for this.. what kind of processing do you do?

Comment: @yi_H: just a standard PC with 64bit Ubuntu, ext4 filesystem, 16Gb RAM, 2TB storage

Comment: @psihoedelia: You'll need more bits of storage than that to store this beast :P

Comment: again, how do you process data? will you constantly seek or can you structure your data in such a way that you can read chunks of sequential data?

Comment: I'm curious, can you tell us more about the data, and how it is going to be used?

Comment: I suggest using a B-Tree (a binary tree using Pages as the nodes).  This may reduce the overhead produced by the link fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As yi_H mentioned in his comment, you'll want a 64 bit operating system and a file system that supports large files. Assuming each node contains on the order of 2^5=32 bytes of data, 2^40 nodes will result in 2^45 bytes = 32 terabytes. Now assuming you're not running on a modern military fighter plane, you'll need to map most of that data to the hard disk.

Once the data is on your disk and the file system is properly configured, I don't think there will be problems with any system limitations. However read/write speed will definitely an issue. Given an average IO speed of 100 mb/s on your hard drive, it would take about 4-5 days to just traverse the entire tree.

It would be better to divide the data up onto multiple computers and parallelize your operations.

Comment: sorry, was my typo; It is about 2**34 nodes expected to be in the tree; about 64 bytes per node should be enough

Comment: Oh that's significantly better. You won't have any trouble with the kernel yelling at you then. ext4 is perfectly fine for 0.5 terabyte files.

Comment: thanks, but are you sure that memory-mapping method is an appropriate one?

Comment: also, if you have multi nodes you can store part of the file in memory, and serving the file (from memory) through network is faster than reading from disk. and even if the nodes read from the disk you'll get good aggregate reading speed (eg: saturate a 10Gbit network card)